# JavaFX in commercial products

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to use JavaFX as a development framework into large commercial product. Can I close the source code of my future product without violation of Oracle's license and sell my product with Oracle JavaFX framework? Are there any license restrictions?

Comment: when you will be creating your project, please, don't be lazy to file issues in javafx-jira. If you are going to use javafx-2.* versions, please, try javafx-8 version at least several times, and if you find any incompability - please, file issues. All of them have non-low probability to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this question, is a dublicate of FAQs questions here :

[JavaFX 2 FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#10)

> What type of license is JavaFX available under? JavaFX is available
>   under the same license and business model as Java SE. This includes
>   the ability for third party developers to distribute the runtime
>   librairies with their application(s), subject to the terms and
>   conditions of the license.

And full licence text can be found here :

[Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for the Java SE Platform Products and JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)

Shortly saying, there is no difference between JavaFX and Java licence now.